# strange behaviour while running tower of hanoi

Tags: java

I am running a very simple program which simulate tower of hanoi.
I print the time taken to move n number (20 to 30) disks.
I see a strange pattern . It takes roughly the same amount of time to move n(even number) and n+1  disks. And to move n+2 disk it takes 4 times of n disks .
I have put the program below. I guess there is some optimization being done in vm when we have multiple recursion calls.
Can anyone put more light on this?

```
public class Hanoi {
    public static void move(int n) {
        if(n > 0) {           
            move(n-1);
            move(n-1);             
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 28;
        move(12);
        for(int n=18; n <= N; n++) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            move(n);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.printf("n=%d t=%d i=%d\n",n, (end-start) , 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your code has tail recursions chances are it will be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

This "problem"?  :-)

If you add IO or some decent computations to the `move` method, you will see that this behavior disappears.  Also, if you just do one `move` recursive call, the program finishes immediately.  Both of these timing anomalies are due to compiler and JIT optimization as Gunner mentioned.  This version of your `move` method for example has much more expected timing:

```
static int[] pieces = new int[100];
public static void move(int n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        // random memory operations
        pieces[n - 1] = pieces[n];
        pieces[n] = pieces[n + 1];
        pieces[n + 1] = pieces[n + 2];
        move(n - 1);
        move(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Here's an interesting piece by IBM about [tail recursion](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-diag8.html).  Here's another [blog posting](http://siddhi.blogspot.com/2006/04/recursion-part-2-tail-recursion.html) about the topic.

Comment: But here the optimization is strange .For example input n=30 and 31 approximately take the same time . But n=32 takes 4 times of 31 but theoretically it should take two times of 31.

Comment: I can't explain that.  Maybe it is doing the unrolling and feels that N+1 is really N with another loop call while N+2 is a large enough difference to optimize it differently.  Again, without doing any real work in move(), and without knowing the intricacies of JIT or the compiler optimizer, I can't say.